# Passing properties file externally to spark-submit Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to pass my application.properties file to my spark-submit command.

This application.properties file is kept on HDFS

```
spark-submit --class TestConfig --files C:\\Myfiles\\application.properties C:\\myjars\\prj-test-0.1.jar
```

In my code i am trying to get it using below code :

```
val sparkPropertiesFile = SparkFiles.get("application.properties")

println("Spark properties : " + sparkPropertiesFile)
val sparkProperties = ConfigFactory.load(sparkPropertiesFile)
val sparkRuntimeConfig = sparkProperties.getConfig("runtime").entrySet().iterator()
```

But this is giving me NullPointer because of this `SparkFiles.get()` option

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$.getRootDirectory(SparkFiles.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$.get(SparkFiles.scala:31)
        at TestConfig$.main(TestConfig.scala:9)
        at TestConfig.main(TestConfig.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

What should be the code/way to read this external property file in my code ..?

Comment: You say the file is kept on HDFS but in your submit command you are providing local path.

Comment: Sorry its on Edge Node

Comment: Did you try providing the path with the prefix `file:///` ?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work that way Reason i found was that as i am submitting on cluster mode the Driver will Run on 1 of the worker node and not on the edge Node so its not able to find that.

Comment: have you got any solution for this ?